# How to properly structure a for loop for looping through python list

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list `A = [1,2,3,4]`

I want to show the lists `[1,2,3] , [2,3,4]`
 
 Here's my solution:

```
A= [5, 3, 3]


def solution(A):
    A.sort()
    #print(A)
    for i in range(0,len(A)-2):
        if i+3 <= len(A):
            part = A[i:i+3]
            if part[0] + part[1] > part[2]:
                print(part)
                return 1
```

I used             `if i+3 <= len(A):`
condition to check length overflow.I don't like the structure, is there a better way to represent this?

Comment: What exact logic are you using to turn `[1,2,3,4]` into `[1,2,3]` and `[2,3,4]`?

Comment: Are you asking how to step through the list and return 3 elements at a time? So if the input were `[1,2,3,4,5]` you'd get `[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]`? Thats the only thing I can think that you might be trying to do, your question isn't clear.

Comment: `list(zip(x,x[1:],x[2:]))`; `zip` stops with the shortest list.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want.

```
for a in range(len(A)-2):
    print(list(A[a:a+3]))

>>> [list(A[a:a+3]) for a in range(len(A)-2)]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]
```